# Не могу авторизоваться с защитой CSRF на PYTHON

Tags: python, post, requests, get

Мне нужно получить данные в каталоге `https://url.ru/contacts` и для получения данных их нужна авторизация `https://url.ru/users/login` с защитой CSRF. Я решил использовать get запрос и по regex вычленить токен и после авторизоваться:

```
import requests
import re

session = requests.Session()
r1 = session.get('https://url.ru/users/login')
csrftoken = re.findall(r"[^\"\>\{\}\\]{86}==", r1.text)
print(r1.cookies)

data={'user[login]': 'login', 'user[password]': 'password', 'user[remember_me]': '0', '_csrf': csrftoken[1]}

r2 = session.post("https://url/users/login", data=data)
print(data)
print(r2.status_code)
print(r2.text)

r = session.get('https://url.ru/contacts/4')
print(r.text)
```

Но на выходе мне в `r` выдает код страницы авторизации

Ссылка на форму: https://2-mk.okdesk.ru/users/sign_in

Answer (score 0):

Ошибка в первом запросе, необходимо их производить в одной сессии

```
r1 = session.get('https://url.ru/users/login')
```

Comment: Исправил. Всё равно выдает мне исходник страницы авторизации. Ссылка на нее help.okdesk.ru/users/sign_in, вдруг я не так вообще авторизацию создаю

Comment: @uppjke рабочий сайт тут не приложен, поэтому не могу посмотреть правильность запроса

Comment: Если этот не пашет, то можно так: 2-mk.okdesk.ru

Comment: добавил ссылку в сам вопрос